# GUI programming in c with Turbo C

Tags: c, windows, user-interface, turbo-c

I need to develop a Gui application but I have three problems: 
1) I'll have to use only C language.
2) I cannot use GTK.
3) I cannot use any other Compiler than Turbo C/C++. (College restriction :/)

Is there any solution for this ?
I am using Windows Operating system.

Comment: I could have done it much before if I can :|

Comment: Turbo C's last version was 25 years ago. If you mean Turbo C++ (which does support C), that was last released 21 years ago.

Comment: Yeah I mean Turbo C/C++. Any solutions ?

Comment: What about Qt, wxWidgets, FLTK, etc?

Comment: Sounds to me like you are going to need to use the Windows API for the graphical user interface to create and manage windows.  So that would be [CreateWindow() function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632679(v=vs.85).aspx) and similar Windows API that have a C interface.

Comment: Turbo can't generate Windows executables, only DOS ones. You could use DOS mouse and graphics libraries to make a DOS-based GUI, but it wouldn't be anything like a Windows app and it wouldn't run on anything newer than Windows XP 32-bit.

Comment: Are you using something like http://www.softpedia.com/get/Programming/Coding-languages-Compilers/TurboCplusplus-for-Windows-7.shtml ?

Comment: @RichardChambers: yes you got it right. I am using it. Any help now ? <br> Does this Turbo version support Windows API ?

Comment: @ooga: All those are c++ library. I can't use them.

Comment: take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3134224/windows-h-in-c-using-turbo-c

Comment: I suggest you discuss this question with your teacher or professor (I assume this is for a class of some kind).  The Windows API for Windows XP is usable from C source code however you will need the proper libraries and the proper DLLs.  Also if Turbo C is a 16 bit compiler then you may run into issues with 32 bit addresses.  Typically you would use a FAR call with FAR address data (32 bit address composed of segment register and offset).  It looks like people have gone to the trouble of creating a dos box, probably some kind of virtual machine thing.  Why aren't people going with Eclipse?

Comment: And you might find this helpful http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE6/en/C%2B%2BBuilder_Developer%27s_Guide though I am not sure if this is the actual Turbo C that you are using.

Comment: Try talking to your teacher first. Perhaps he also dislikes TurboC but is also forced (by his management) to use it.

Comment: @haccks this is not necessarily a bad thing. Working with constraints is a good way to teach the basics. Working with something ancient is a way to make sure your teaching knowledge and materials aren't obsolete. The goal isn't to teach you something you can use to get a job tomorrow, it's to teach the fundamentals. I'm so glad to have grown gradually along with the industry, rather than try to drink from the firehose today.

Comment: @MarkRansom; I agreed with your views. But, in most cases the scenario is something like this: "*I am an old guy who learned programming on Turbo C++ and do not upgraded my self yet. So, you have to learn my way*". I know a professor in my college who teach us Numerical Analysis and he was a big fan of `goto` statement. He looks for that statement in programs. If the written program is correct and `goto` is not used then he gave us 2 or 3 out of 5. If program is wrong but contains some `goto`, then he gave us `3.5` to `4` out of `5` points.

Comment: @MarkRansom; And yes, I also do not believe in drinking from fire hose.

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can , The library you'll have to use is called #include "graphics.h" . It's a very primitive library and there are methods ( or functions I should rather say ) for Decorating Text , outputting pixels and drawing very primitive shapes .

for eg) drawCircle(int x,int y, int radius) where  x and y are the co-ordinates of the circle

The origin of the co-ordinate system lies to the top left of the Black screen that appears when you press Run on turbo C . It increases towards the right as the x co-ordinate and towards the bottom as the y co-ordinate .

There are no inbuilt functions for translations so if you will have to animate by first drawing a completely black shape over the exact shape you want to move , then move the shape's co-ordinate and then draw it again.  There are a host of other things and you can check it out in the help index

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the GUI system you want.

If you want something similar to todays' GUI then you can use the `graphics.h` library as sugested by user1771825.

However if you prefer a more *console* or *dos* look, i.e., a text based GUI, then just use instructions like `textcolor`, `textbackground`, `window` and such, or use inline assembler to control the foreground and background colors, text positions and the rest.
This is what I used back then to build pull downs menus, dialogs and windows.